# Parital Refund with channel advisor Issue

Tags: rest, api, netsuite, channeladvisor

Anyone familiar with Partial Refunds in channel Advisor ?

I am Working with channel advisor API for Refund, I Could'nt refund the amount using API Anyone knows the channel advisor refund API Request?

Also I couldnt find the selleradjustmentID in my order, What is seller adjustment id For an order in ChannelAdvisor?

POST https://api.channeladvisor.com/v1/OrderItems(12345678)/Adjust?access_token=xxxxxxxxxx
{
    "Reason": "CustomerReturnedItem",
    "SellerAdjustmentID": "SampleAdjustmentID-12345",
    "Quantity": 1
}